# Can I call a PHP function from within a MySQL query?

Tags: php

I am quite new to PHP/MySQL and I would like to know whether it is possible to use a PHP function in a UPDATE statement, like this:

```
<?php
function myfun($a) {
   $a = $a + 1;
   return $a;
}

mysql_query("UPDATE `my_table` SET `myfield` = myfun(`par`)");
?>
```

Comment: @Domenico G you could get the return of a function and paste it in the query (see updated answer)

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted, to someone new to PHP/MySQL that's a completely valid question. Obviously the request CAN be done as Stevanicus answered below, Domenico just had the wrong implementation which is understanding being new and all. Sheesh people.

Comment: @bowlerae: (a) Look at the edit history; it wasn't even close to valid PHP and wasn't formatted at all. (b) The endgame is not specified; the requirement is underspecified. It's a poor question.

Answer (score 2):

no you can only do the following

[update mysql with php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

you could do the following tho

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET myfield = '".myfunction(par)."'");
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET myfield = '".myfunction(par)."'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

**UPDATE**
is this what you mean?

```
updateTable(10);

function updateTable($num){
   for($i = 0; $i<$num; $i++){
       mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET myfield = '".$i."'");
   }
}
```

Comment: if I write : function Increment(){
static   $jVal;
$jVal = $jVal + 1;
return $jVal;
}

for ($kk=1 ; $kk<=10; $kk+=1){
echo increment();
echo "<br />";
} The loop is working very well, but if I use $querymod = "UPDATE comnaz set comnaz_id='" . increment() . "'";
or
$querymod = "UPDATE comnaz set comnaz_id=' . increment() . '";
it doe not make ANY update on the table ...

Comment: @Domenico G if i understood you correctly, i have updated the answer

Comment: @Stevanicus: IMO he wants to apply the function to a field in the table. i.e. the function should be executed _within_ the query, not used to _compose_ the query.

Answer (score 0):

No. No, it's not.

These are two independent and distinct technologies, implemented by two separate processes.

However, [you can define procedures in MySQL itself](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)...

Comment: function Increment(){
static   $jVal;
$jVal = $jVal + 1;
return $jVal;
}

for ($kk=1 ; $kk<=10; $kk+=1){
echo increment();
echo "<br />";
}

Comment: Thank you .... but HOW to DEFINE the procedures?